# Nepal visa on arrival payment method

Tags: us-citizens, visas-on-arrival, nepal

I will be arriving in Nepal tomorrow and I’m getting mixed information on how to pay for the visa on arrival.

Some sites say cash only, some say I can use a credit card.

Does anyone have recent experience with paying for the visa on arrival? My US currency is quite low, but I have quite a bit of Chinese, Vietnamese, and Thai currency.

I will be arriving at Kathmandu international airport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so here is the immigration area for Visa on Arrival in Nepal:

When you get into the arrival terminal head to your right towards the little kiosks:

[image]

From there you will scan your passport and fill out the info on the screen. There was a nice lady helping people and she spoke excellent English when I arrived, so that helped. Get your printed ticket.

Next, head back in the direction you came from and you will see this counter:

[image]

Here are the currencies they accept and yes they do accept credit card (you can see in the image above on the left)!

[image]

Once you pay for your visa head to the immigration officers (not the visa gratis lane) and you’re all set.

The process was super simple and very fast, at least until you get to customs!

Answer (score 2):

[Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/nepal/visas) says the Katmandu airport officials accept "any major currency" but land borders only accept USD.

The [official site](http://nepalimmigration.gov.np/page/tourist-visa) says:

While you can use different modes of payments (at visa fees collection counter), we advise 
you to carry some cash to be on the safe side.

[This site](https://www.welcomenepal.com/plan-your-trip/visa-nepal-information.html) is a bit more dubious but claims "Euro, Swiss Franc, Pound Sterling, US Dollar, Australian Dollar, Canadian Dollar, Hong Kong Dollar, Singapore Dollar and Japanese Yen".

Since you have none of those currencies (perhaps the fact Chinese don't have to pay for the visa means they don't accept CNY), and it appears credit card payment is probably not possible, at least not reliably, I would suggest carrying something like USD or maybe Euros since "tomorrow" is very close.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to get some USD so I will know for sure in a few hours. Thanks for the response, once I get confirmation I’ll comment with that info to help solidify this answer

Comment: @TravelLikeBeaker Safe travels. You can also answer your question yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1st  Step
Fill in ' Arrival Card '
Fill in Online ‘Tourist Visa ‘form ( you can fill it up  prior to your arrival  visiting official website of Department of Immigration / fill it up using Kiosk machines upon your arrival at the airport).  If you fill it from the website, you will get submission Receipt with barcode, please print it out and bring it along for acquiring visa. It works for fifteen days and becomes invalid then after.  If so, you will have to fill it up again.
2nd  Step
Make payment  at the bank according to your visa requirement ( 15/30/90 Days)
Get the receipt
While you can use different modes of payments (at visa fees collection counter), we advise you to carry some cash to be on the safe side.

On Arrival Visa Fee

15 Days – 30 USD

30 Days – 50 USD

90 Days – 125 USD

3rd Step
Proceed to the Immigration Desk with your online form,  payment receipts and your passport
Hand in your documents to immigration officer for visa processing. He/she issues visa to you upon his/her satisfaction.

According to [Nepal Immigration](https://www.immigration.gov.np/page/visa-on-arrival)